# Am I doing this API Put request correct with mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express, mongoose

So I'm using mongoose and mongodb and express routing to do it.

I have a user document with an empty array on creation- "todolist", I want to be able to edit this to add a task to the list as well as edit those tasks.

Right now I'm thinking the best way to do it is have the server check if the req.body has certain variables set to know which part of the document I need to edit.

Is this the correct approach or am I suppose to create a new API route for something like this or am I doing it correctly by checking req variables from the client to determine what I want to edit on the server? Is there a cleaner way to do this too?

```
router.put('/:user_id', function(req, res) {
    User.findById(req.params.user_id, function(err, user){
        if(err){
            res.send(err);
            return err;
        }

        if(req.body.createTask) {
            user.todolist.push({
                "task_name": req.body.task_name,
                "task_importance": req.body.importance,
                "task_completed": false
            })
        }else if(req.body.edit_task){
            if(req.body.edit_task_name) {
                user.todolist[req.body.index].task_name = req.body.new_task_name;
            }else if(req.body.edit_task_importance) {
                user.todolist[req.body.index].task_importance = req.body.new_task_importance;
            }else if(req.body.edit_task_completed) {
                user.todolist[req.body.index].task_completed = true;
            }
        }

        user.save(function(err){
            if(err)
                res.send(err);
            res.json({message: 'User updated'});
        })
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to model your database with proper entities, creating a Task model separately from User and adding a reference to User, like this:

```js
var TaskSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  name: String,
  importance: String,
  completed: Boolean
});
```

If you want to, you can also add reference to Task on User:

```js
var User = new mongoose.Schema({
  // note this is an array
  todolist: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Task'
  }]
});
```

Doing that, to make things simpler, you should create a [pre save hook](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) to automatically add tasks to user:

```js
TaskSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  if (this.isModified('user') && this.user) {
    // $addToSet will add this document to the user's todolist (if it's not already there)
    User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: this.user}, {$addToSet: {todolist: this}}, function(err, doc) {
      next(err);
    })
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

This way the correct approach would be provide endpoints correlated to entities. So, to create a task, a user should request `POST /tasks` with body `{ user: '123', name: 'name', ... }`:

```js
router.post('/tasks', function(req, res) {
  Task.create(req.body, function(err, task) {
    if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);
    return res.status(201).json(task);
  });
});
```

It will automatically add the task to the user `123` with our pre save hook.
To edit the task, just make that on task endpoint:

```js
router.put('/tasks/:id', function(req, res) {
  Task.findById(req.params.id, function(err, task) {
    if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);
    if (!task) return res.status(404).send('Not Found');

    task.name = req.body.name || task.name;
    task.importance = req.body.importance || task.importance;
    task.completed = true;

    task.save(function(err, task) {
      if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);
      res.status(200).json(task);
    });
  });
});
```

You don't need to edit user as it only keeps tasks reference.

If you want to get users with tasks data populated (and not only their ids), just do:

```js
router.get('/users', function(req, res) {
  User.find({}).populate('todolist').exec(function(err, users) {
    ...
  });
});
```

For queries like that above, I recommend you to use some library like [querymen](https://github.com/diegohaz/querymen), which parses querystrings (e.g. `GET /users?q=Some+Search&limit=10&page=2`) to MongoDB query arguments.

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Wouldn't this scenario be better to keep all the data embedded in User's schema though? Since every User only has one set of tasks and there wont be a lot of tasks

Comment: It's a decision you should make. I recommend you to separate them because in the future, as your system grows, you can improve the task entity with more flexibility without having to edit user entity.

Comment: Also, for scalability, it's better to have separated small collections than a giant one. Learn more [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/)

Comment: If you still want to embed tasks in user (which isn't wrong), I'd recommend you to create endpoints like `POST /users/:userId/tasks` and `PUT /users/:userId/tasks/:taskId` to be more clear.

Comment: Okay thanks. Another question I've been wondering all day.. (this is the first time Im making a restful api btw) but how is the client making the api request going to know the userID wouldn't it work much better if it used the user name instead of the id?

Comment: You can use username as well, but, for consistency it's better to use id, as you may reference it in other parts of your API (for `POST /tasks` for example). You usually will make a GET request before any other requests (e.g. `GET /users/me`).

Comment: If this answer satisfies you don't forget to choose it as the best answer.

Comment: hmm.. so for my unit tests.. how would i test that GET /users/me returns the correct id if i have nothing to check it with? And since id need that id to run the rest of my tests isnt that a dilemma? should i save the id when i first create the user in the test? how would i do that?

Comment: I don't know if I understand your point. Do you know that MongoDB automatically creates an '_id' attribute for each document you save? It's better to you to create another thread for that question, but you don't unit test endpoints (you do integration tests instead). And, usually, when testing, you must mock some data in database.